# Node.js regex remove apostrophes inside urls

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, nodes

I'd need to replace all apostrophes inside my strings, only the ones in the href=" " tag, apostrophe outside should remain.

I'm using node.js.

Here my string:

```
This is an example text. I'd love to fix this. 

<a href="https://www.example.com/i'd-love-to-fly/"> I'd love to fly link </a> 

Inside the text there could be more urls 

<a href="https://www.example.com/i'd-rather/">I'd rather link</a>.
```

for example

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/i'd-love-to-fly/"> I'd love to fly link </a>
```

should be

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/id-love-to-fly/"> I'd love to fly link </a>
```

I'm trying to use regex

```
/https[^"]++/
```

it selects the whole URL but then I don't know how to select and replace only the apostrophe

Comment: Cant u just use replace? `"https://www.example.com/i'd-love-to-fly/".replace("'","")`

Comment: My strings doesn't have only the url and I don't know the specific url. For example, my string is: ```example of my string with ', then there's a random url <a href="https://www.example.com/i'd-love-to-fly/"> I'd love to fly link </a>  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it assuming you only have a single single-quote inside the URL:

```
(href="[^"]+)'([^"]+")
```

https://regex101.com/r/6zRLSC/1

If you have multiple single-quotes then a while loop can address that issue.

```js
 var string = `This is an example text. I'd love to fix this. 

<a href="https://www.example.com/i'd-love-to-fly-but-don't-like-heights/"> I'd love to fly but don't like heights link </a> 

Inside the text there could be more urls 

<a href="https://www.example.com/i'd-rather/">I'd rather link</a>.`;

// While we match the pattern that we're targeting, keep on replacing
while(string.match(/(href="[^"]+)'([^"]+")/))
{
    string = string.replace(/(href="[^"]+)'([^"]+")/g, '$1$2')
}

console.log(string);
```

Comment: thank you a lot! Just a stupid question, variables $1 and $2 are basically the regex groups?

Comment: @vamp Correct. In the regex I made use of parenthesis for the start and end of the href which saves the data into a capture group for later use; respectively `$1` and `$2`.